# "His jacket was tied about his waist schoolboy style..."

Tags: grammaticality-in-context

> A tall boy with reddish hair in jeans and a T-shirt.  His jacket was tied about his waist ***schoolboy style*** and flapped wildly around his knees.

I don't know what ***schoolboy style*** is doing grammatically.  Is it an adverbial phrase? How should we understand it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, "schoolboy style" is acting as an adverb modifying the verb "tied".

The suffix "style" (sometimes written as two words as here, sometimes hyphenated like "schoolboy-style") means "in the style of", or even more explicitly "in the style often adopted by", so we could reword the phrase as:

> His jacket was tied ... in the style often adopted by schoolboys

Answer (score 2):

The author wants to clear the image by stating that 'style'. Probably, it's a pretty common style adapted by schoolboys.

Like this -

[image: schoolboy with jacket tied]

Comment: That picture is not very clear. The style is to tie the jacket arms around your waist, with the jacket body falling from your waist to your knees.